# How can I detect a system time change event in UWP/WinUI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, winui

#### Problem

I want to be able to detect when the user changes the time in the Windows settings menu (timezone changes and auto-changes may be helpful to detect too). On application startup, I am currently checking an NTP server to check if the user's system time is correct. However, I need to be able to recheck if anything changes.

I am able to look out for this on Android using a Broadcast receiver that looks for: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED

On iOS, I was able to use: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622992-applicationsignificanttimechange

#### What I've tried

I'm using Xamarin.Forms. I was able to use Xamarin.Android + Xamarin.iOS code to implement the solution for those platforms. I am looking for a native UWP/WinUI solution to listen out for a similar user action.

I've been able to find some old .NET code that would apply to Win32 or .NET Framework which is no good: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

I can see some modern APIs that can be used for detecting time zone changes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.timezonesettings?view=winrt-22621 But that doesn't cover the user going and manually changing the date/time.

Or running background tasks at a fixed rate to check for the date time but this seems inefficient: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.TimeTrigger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22621 It would be much better if the system broadcast an event and I could listen for that.

What is the best method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

UWP doesn't have an API that could detect the system time change directly. UWP could only detect the TimeZone change using the [SystemTrigger.TimeZoneChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype?view=winrt-22621) in the background task. The [SystemEvents.TimeChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) you found should be the way to detect the time change.

Comment: SystemEvents.TimeChanged won't work in UWP though will it? It will only be after migrating to Maui and using WinUI that I could potentially even call that API right?

Comment: @BurkusCat You might need to call that API in a desktop app like a console app. Then package the uwp app together with the console app using desktop bridge.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, does UWP has any API support to detect system time change directly? Is there any easier / updated way available now?

Comment: @Md.FaisalHabib No. If you want, use the win32 API instead.